# Python scikit learn MLPClassifier “hidden_layer_sizes” varargs

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in this portion of code :

```
arr = [15,10,5]
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(*arr),activation = 'tanh', max_iter=100)
```

this error is showing:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(*a),activation = 'tanh', max_iter=100)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to pass an array as `vararg`s in MLPClassifier `hidden_layer_sizes` parameter?

Comment: Have you tried passing it as `hidden_layer_sizes=tuple(arr)` ?

Comment: yes but it showing some errors, but code is running

Comment: Is the error still the same as you mentioned or you get a different error?

It will throw an error if you try to unwrap a list into a tuple using `(*arr)` You can either declare `arr = (15, 10, 5)` and set `hidden_layer_size=arr` or type cast it `hidden_layer_sizes=tuple(arr)`

Or if you wish to use your syntax, you may consider adding a `,` after arr => `(*arr,)`

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py:571: ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (100) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.
  % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)
71.11111111111111                                                                   this is the error but output is showing